# Iframe Click data, precise on the pixels

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I was wondering if i could get the click data from users of my iframe, precise on the pixel.

My banner/iframe is 728x90, Is there any way i can see on which pixel the user clicked in the iframe? Thanks.

Comment: clientX, clientY https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX

Comment: Only if the iframe is in the same domain. Not sure what Java/PHP has to do with this.

Comment: Okay. I advertise on another site and i am quite suspicious about the amount of clicks it gets. I guess there is no way to check then i guess.